# What fast image viewers are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

What is the fastest / most responsive image viewer?

I'm looking for a program that is responsive and opens large `.jpg`s fast - progressively and/or by cleverly loading only parts it will render. A 6 MB picture has a resolution of 4000x3000, while my eeePC only has 1024x600, so I won't see a lot of the pixels anyway. Another technique is to cache pictures in the background while I'm viewing the first. A lot of programs on Windows do stuff like that, is there anything you can recommend for an eeePC running Ubuntu?

**Context:** I recently switched to XFCE to revive my eeePC (as Gnome Shell and Unity are somewhat slow on it). I'm generally satisfied as it runs pretty snappy, and I can get work done on the go. However, I'd like to organize some fotos that I have, and all the image viewers I tried are too slow. For example, Ristretto, XFCE's lean image viewer, takes about a second to open a picture of 1.8 MB (5 seconds for a 6 MB picture), and freezes in that time.

Comment: People that can add tags: Maybe you should consider a [tag:low-end] tag for questions about running Ubuntu on low-end or older hardware? (Alternatively we could have a tag concerning lean and fast setups of Ubuntu.)

Comment: I'm not having problems with the loading time of the *applications*, but rather with the loading time of the *images*. Eye of Gnome, Shotwell, Ristretto, GPicView, all load fast enough and their interface works fine. I can even run Digikam, which has a long startup time but once loaded is OK. I'm looking mainly for something that lets me switch quickly between large images, not necessarily for a minimal GUI.

Comment: I see what you mean, though in my answer I do mention that you can flick between very high resolution images in slideshow mode with `feh` much quicker than `gthumb`, etc. Loading of the images is the focus in my answer below; ignore the comment I made above about loading times of the programs.

Comment: Please jdm, mark one of the answers as accepted if you find some of them useful.

Comment: There is a rather small number of actually different free jpeg decoder implementations out there. I'm guessing that most image viewers use the standard libjpeg6 library, which is included by default by pretty much all Linux distributions and was last updated back in 1998. That code is just the JPEG group's free reference code. Viewers that embed their own decoder probably also just use something based on the reference implementation.  So, speed differences will be based on how efficiently the app handles the pixels after they come out of decoder and if they do pre-fetching.

Comment: I use standard one

Comment: Tried 1) `Viewnoir` 2) `Mirage` 3) `Nomacs` 4) `Phototonic`. All of these are slow with large images. No option to configure `prefetch next 'n'` images.

Answer (score 41):

## [GPicView](http://lxde.sourceforge.net/gpicview/)

I'll recommend to you this Simple and Fast image viewer.

As you say that you computer is not a super fast calculator you should look for software with a few functions (the fewest possible), and this software meets this requirement, see the next screen-shoot and you will notice it.

[image: ss]

You can install it through the [Software-Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpicview/).

Comment: @jdm I'm hoping that this software works well with your computer. Please, let me know the performance that you get.

Comment: Does it do image pre-fetching?

Comment: @Flimm I couldn't understand you. What do you mean with *prefetching*? See the image before *open* it (as mouse-over)?

Comment: I mean: does it load the next image in the slideshow into RAM, before actually displaying it? This makes displaying the next image instantaneous (at least when you've spent a couple of seconds viewing the current image).

Comment: And how will I know that? My computer is a QuadCore, I will never notice that (from the front-end).

Comment: Maybe it's documented somewhere? Don't worry about it.

Comment: Just installed it and it is exactly what I was looking for. Now I am able to quickly open images from the command line! thanks

Comment: Great tip! This should marked as answer.

By the way @lucio what's the name of your icon theme?

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping too that the OP will mark an answer as *accepted*. Sorry but I have no idea of what icon them is that one.

Comment: There is no reason for software with "few functions (the fewest possible)" to be fast. That is a luddite point of view.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky in general software development you know that adding a functionality you're adding size and memory usage to your application. Hence, more functions the slowest the application will be in an environment with poor resources.

Comment: @Lucio Using more memory is usually a good way to gain speed. For example, pre-caching images. Your views are outdated. Are you working on a Pentium MMX?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky not really buddy. Just on a eeePC lol

Comment: when deleting a file, unfortunately it completely removes it instead of moving it to the trash.

Comment: @Blauhirn can be changed around src/main-win.c:1400 though

Comment: @Flimm it does **not** do image pre-fetching

Answer (score 25):

For sheer speed, `feh` is the most responsive image viewer you'll ever come across; it might take a bit of getting used to as it is managed from the command line. However, you can add various `feh` commands as custom actions to filemanagers such as `Nautilus` and `Thunar` so that you can activate `feh` via the context menu when browsing your files.

On the man page it is noted that:

> Feh is a mode-based image viewer.  It is especially aimed at commandline users who need a fast image viewer without huge GUI dependencies, though it can also be started by (graphical) file managers to view an image. It supports filelists, various image sorting modes, image captions and more... Configurable keyboard shortcuts are used to control it.

**Some examples of usage:**

`Feh` operates in various modes such as slideshow, montage, index, and thumbnail, although you can of course view pictures individually, and also save the results of the index or thumbnail viewing to file.

All the following examples assume you use terminal to `cd` to the folder containing the pictures first:

1) To start a fullscreen slideshow, and for it to display all the loadable pictures in the folder with a 3 second gap and then exit, you could run:

```
feh -F -D 3 --cycle-once *
```

You can use your mouse scrollwheel to flick back and forth through the pictures while the slideshow is running. Even with high resolution pictures (5-6 mb each), you can flick through the pictures incredibly quickly.

You could also add this command, with slight modification, as a 'custom' action, context menu item in a file manager such as `Thunar` (`feh -F -D 3 --cycle-once %F`): see my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18367/how-to-customize-files-context-menu-in-xubuntu-xfce-thunar-file-manager/193769#193769) regarding `Thunar` custom actions.

**Note**: when not running in fullscreen mode (`-F`), you may need to supply the `--scale-down` command switch so the pictures fill your desktop, but not display at their actual size (which could be 4000x3000 and would not fit the screen).

```
feh --scale-down picture.jpg
```

Hence your custom 'open-with' command/launcher should use this `--scale-down` option, for the times you want to view individual pictures.

2) In the case of creating an index print and saving to file you could use the following command:

```
feh -I --preload -o index.png
```

3) You can also use the thumbnail option (`-t`), which is like the previous command, but allows you to click the thumbnails from the created file:

```
feh -t --preload --scale-down -o thumbprint.png
```

You can do a lot more with `feh` and there are many more options to experiment with, so for more information, please see `man feh` and the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/feh.1.html).

Comment: Does it do image pre-fetching?

Comment: @Flimm I'm not sure, however, the `--preload` switch above is just about eliminating non image types when collating an index or thumbnail print.

Comment: I am usually looking for `feh -FZ *`

Comment: I really like feh. I wanted a slideshow where images are cycled at a 5 minutes interval and both other options I tried (gThumb & native Ubuntu viewer) were limited to 100 seconds. Why would a developer put in that limitation is totally beyond me, but feh saved the day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 24):

**Viewnior**

[Viewnior](http://siyanpanayotov.com/project/viewnior/download/) has been the fastest image viewer for me by far:

[image]

One more reason to choose Viewnior is that isn't affected by [this image scaling bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665897) that's prevalent in many other GTK-based image viewers (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/131233/81372) for other solutions to this bug).

---

**Installation**

*Ubuntu 14.10 and up*

As of Ubuntu 14.10 Viewnior is now part of the official Ubuntu repositories. You can install it from the Software Centre or by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install viewnior
```

*Earlier Ubuntu releases*

A third-party PPA for Viewnior is now available. Before proceeding with the installation please make sure to read the following Q&As on PPAs and their potential dangers:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

If you are confident with adding a third-party PPA you can install Viewnior by using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:desdelinux/viewnior
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install viewnior
```

Source: http://blog.desdelinux.net/instala-viewnior-en-ubuntu-12-04-13-10-14-04-ppa/

---

Alternatively you can compile Viewnior from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/xsisqox/Viewnior.git
cd Viewnior
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

Instead of using checkinstall to generate a debian package and install it via the package manager you can just as well run `make install`. With this method you won't be able to manage your installation from the package manager, though.

Comment: *The fastest image viewer by far has been Viewnior **for me*** And what computer do you have?

Comment: @Lucio Standard Core i5 Notebook with Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Don't see how my computer setup would be relevant. Performance differences should be visible across the borders. Viewnior also comes with a lot more features. You should try it out.

Comment: Yes, I know, it is a excellent software. But I was referring that this image viewer is *too* good for the OP's computer (*high* resources requirement). Also, I think that any image viewer will be really fast with that CPU, you computer is great!

Comment: Ah, you're right of course. I had overlooked that the OP is sporting an EEE PC. I'm afraid I don't know if Viewnior is lightweight enough for that system. But it won't hurt to try it out, either. As to the CPU I agree. It really is a great system. Still, I do see performance differences between EOG and gpicview/Viewnior. (EOG also has a bug with supersampling/downscaling that makes high resolution pictures look ugly when zoomed out. That's what brought me to Viewnior initially.)

Comment: Excellent! super fast for me too! Ubuntu 14.04 here

Comment: Thanks!  Would never have found this otherwise. It's great for Ubuntu 17.10!  Displays images "image viewer" cannot.

Comment: For viewing ONLY, another very fast one with gui is "Mirage".

Comment: The repo is gone, I think; it doesn't contain the source code anymore

Answer (score 16):

That's quite sad, but the fastest viewer for my PC (mobile core i5 2nd gen and ssd) is [Picasa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9) installed in Wine.
I've compared following viewers while browsing quickly through hundreds of 3MB jpgs:

- Picasa 3.9 in Wine - instant (yes, if browsing very quickly you may see previews in lesser quality, but you still don't have to wait, while it's loading, as in every other viewer mentioned below)
- XNViewMP 0.72 - faster than "very fast" but slower than instant :)
- Viewnior 1.4-2 - very fast
- GPicView 0.2.4-1 - fast
- gThumb 3:3.3.1 - average
- Eye of GNOME 3.12.2 (default on Ubuntu) - terribly slow
- Shotwell Viewer 0.20.2 - terribly slow

P.S: PicasaPhotoViewer.exe is actually a viewer, not Picasa3.exe

Comment: I just opened thousands of files in Shotwell 0.30.10 on Ubuntu 20.04, and it doesn't seem slow.

Answer (score 3):

**Mcomix** actually not a traditional "image" viewer but a comic reader but since it preloads all pictures in a folder/zip/rar/whatever it is instant when switching pictures (turing a page) + there is a small preview  on the side where one can see which pictures are already preloaded

Comment: Works great!
Only one issue, though: It doesn't sense the orientation exif tag, so images need to be rotated manually by pressing `R` or `Shift+R`

Answer (score 0):

Phototonic,
it is fast, nice, very functional and offers an easy navigation plus basic options.
As most image-viewers for Ubuntu it is missing xcf-support (as far as I know unfortunately only Gwenview (depends on KDE4) and gThumb have this)