# Alternative image viewers

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I dont really like Eye of Gnome (EOG).

What other image viewers are available for Ubuntu?

I am using `gwenview` but it takes a long time to load.

Comment: Another option is `feh` (`apt install feh`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can also use `gpicview`.

you can install with `sudo apt-get install gpicview`

and you can also install `pinta`

```
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

for gpicview

[image: Install via the software center]

for pinta

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: +1 for `gpicview`, which starts fast. See [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/eye-of-gnome/?platform=linux) for other alternatives.

Comment: Plus gpicview doesn't [hang](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/1393227) when you launch multiple instances from varying source-folders.

Answer (score 16):

### Viewnior

---

I particularly like [Viewnior](http://siyanpanayotov.com/project/viewnior/). It's a very lightweight and fast image viewer - faster than any of the alternatives I've tried:

[image]

One more reason to choose Viewnior is that isn't affected by [this image scaling bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665897) that's prevalent in many other GTK-based image viewers (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/131233/81372) for other solutions to this bug).

---

**Installation**

*Ubuntu 14.10 and up*

As of Ubuntu 14.10 Viewnior is now part of the official Ubuntu repositories. You can install it from the Software Centre or by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install viewnior
```

*Earlier Ubuntu releases*

A third-party PPA for Viewnior is now available. Before proceeding with the installation please make sure to read the following Q&As on PPAs and their potential dangers:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

If you are confident with adding a third-party PPA you can install Viewnior by using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:desdelinux/viewnior
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install viewnior
```

Source: http://blog.desdelinux.net/instala-viewnior-en-ubuntu-12-04-13-10-14-04-ppa/

---

Alternatively you can compile Viewnior from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/xsisqox/Viewnior.git
cd Viewnior
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

Instead of using checkinstall to generate a debian package and install it via the package manager you can just as well run `make install`. With this method you won't be able to manage your installation from the package manager, though.

Comment: Awesome image viewer. Faster, less buggy and better default behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

#### gThumb

gThumb is an advanced image viewer and browser. It has many useful features, such as filesystem browsing, slide show, image catalogs, web album creation, camera import, image CD burning, batch file operations and quick image editing features like transformation and color manipulation.

It's designed for GNOME desktop environment and uses its platform. For camera import feature, the gPhoto2 library is used.

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

[image]

Comment: pro: files get moved to trash, not deleted permanently. the other viewers do not support this feature.

Answer (score 4):

The best one [XNVIEW MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is missing. It is something like Faststone image viewer for Windows. 26 Mb size, lots of options, and you can convert formats as well.

It is not in the software center, but you can download it from the official site and open it with the software center. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either GIMP, or Shotwell Photo Manager.  To install GIMP, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

And for Shotwell Photo Manager,

```
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

Or just click the images below

For GIMP: [image: Install via the software center]

For Shotwell: [image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 1):

#### Mirage

is pretty lightweight and simple, but still has renaming, resizing, cropping and especially to me an essential thing, the status bar. I'm not sure if is reading EXIF data, but it does not seem to rotate the images based on EXIF orientation information.

```
sudo apt-get install mirage
```

[image: Install via the software center]

At the time of writing this, there's a newer version in a 3rd party PPA (1.0 vs. 0.9.5.1), but at least on my 14.04 Cinnamon installation there was an issue with not remembering the last window size, which is not present in the older version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vexo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mirage
```

[image: Mirage]

Answer (score 0):

I love XN-View too. There a few more Tools from XN-Soft:

XN-View: [XN-Soft](http://www.xnview.com/en/)

XN-Convert: [XN-Convert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/)

and XN-Retro.

All Tools are for Ubuntu. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use fbi to view all pictures in folder with loop option:

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install fbi
```

Usage:

```
fbi -noverbose -a -u -t 5 /home/User/Desktop/Wallpapers/* -T 1
```