# Do Sony cameras with memory stick work with Ubuntu?

Tags: sony, camera

I'm considering buying a Sony Cybershot camera that uses memory stick. Would Ubuntu have any problems working with that format? Can I just connect the camera to my computer using USB cable to upload photos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can connect it to Ubuntu with out any problems and It will usually detect as a Memory card that similar to Connecting your mobile SD card to Ubuntu system.

You can synchronize them also.

Here a list of best image viewers & by clicking it them you can find features.

[Alternative image viewers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295702/alternative-image-viewer)

Answer (score 2):

No issues at all, I can connect my SONY RX-100 and RX-1 directly with Ubuntu and use Shotwell to download photos or take the card out and put it in the card reader of my laptop to read the photos.