# Looking for some graphics and text viewer

Tags: doublecmd

I'm looking for a lightweight program that can display graphics **and text** files, to replace built-in doublecommander viewer (f3). Can you recommend something please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative image viewers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295702/alternative-image-viewers)

Comment: @muru these viewers can't show text files.

Comment: `emacs` (I have emacs24 (version 24.5+1-6ubuntu1)  from the repositories in 16.04.1 LTS).

Comment: @sudodus thanks, I'll try, but it looks too complicated for my simple tasks :(

Comment: The standard solution is to use the standard file manager (Files alias nautilus in standard Ubuntu) and let it select what program to use, when you double-click on a file. I think that for this reason, there is no big incentive to create the kind of combo file reader, that you want.

Comment: @sudodus no, I don't want to launch everything! I just want quick see files sources. doublecmd (and also totalcmd for windows) has this feature by default, but in doublecmd it works very badly.